# Access other Web API from my Web API

Tags: json, api, curl, servicestack

I have a requirement to make **Endpoint calls to multiple Web API's designed by other companies**. These calls will be made on periodic basis like once an hour, or once a day to post and retrieve some data (business to business transactions). Am working with .NET framework and ServiceStack.

Am not sure, what would be the best approach to achieve this type of functionality?

Maybe, I can have a Windows Service application which scans through the relevant config tables in SQL Server and generate **CURL commands and execute them?** Not sure, whether this will be the correct approach or there is something better you would like to propose?

I have never worked with CURL before, these are just initial thoughts.

Comment: Please state what you're trying to achieve, is it the periodic calls that you're worried about? What is the client issuing the requests implemented in? Just a bit confused that you mention .net and service stack and also curl? Is this about translating curl calls to .net requests?

Comment: The consumer calls my API Endpoint to POST some information and that is fine. I also need to perform some POSTs to other API's for an example Facebook, Google, Yahoo, etc in the background.

Comment: And what is the trouble with that?

Comment: I don't want to do make posts to Facebook, Google and Yahoo immediately but I prefer to do periodically say once in every 30 minutes by using some sort of automatic job which sweeps the outstanding data. and I don't know what would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this your backend needs a data structure to hold all necessary data for the requests (which can be a database table as you suggest) and a scheduling mechanism. This could be as simple as a timer and when triggered it picks up the requests and executes them (by using the built-in `HttpClient` for instance). IMO you should keep this logic within the application itself, no need to make things complicated by introducing a system-dependant service that then issues curl commands on the os level.

Comment: I think HttpClient is the key in this answer! Many Thanks!